# What exactly is Qt and how do I make a GUI using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, libraries

I have a project in my class which takes a .csv file, parses through the data, and creates graphs based on the data inputted from the .csv file.

My job is to create a GUI, along with 2 others. Our prof told us to use Qt, so I've been researching Qt and noticed that there website wants us to pay for it. I figured there was a free version, which eventually I did find. When downloading I noticed it was 10-12GB, which is huge.

Initially I was under the impression that Qt was a library that could be imported into a c++ file, and now I'm fairly confident that it's not.

Can anyone explain exactly what Qt is, and how I can import it into a c++ file? If it means anything I'm using xCode on a mac, but my group members are using mostly windows, and one person is using Linux.

People didn't seem to find my question very clear. I thought there would be a file that I downloaded and put into the source folder of my project. Thus a simple import statement would do the trick.

I'm fairly new to programming, so I don't know the terminology very well.

Comment: Have you tried browsing the [documentation on the Qt website](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/osx.html)?

Comment: QT is quicktime, and you cannot make GUI with it ;)

Comment: Click the "info" tab on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info

Comment: Behind many clicks and questions you should get to this page: http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2
 Where you can download the free version, the offline installer is about 700MB

Comment: When I download qt for OS X, will the GUI still be able to launch on all operating systems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[That](http://www.qt.io/)'s Qt.
[That](http://www.qt.io/developers/)'s how to use it.

*Qt* is a C++ framework built up of many libraries, with an amazing (let me call it) extension called *QML* to create fluid ui. While the former is completely C++ based, the latter defines a new declarative language that let the users to embed JavaScript code and you can freely and easily exports and access classes and objects belonging to a world from the other one (as an example, you can query the QML objects from within your C++ code and interact with them, you can even export C++ objects to the QML environment to add new functionalities and so on).

As any other library (for Qt is composed by many libraries) you *have to* include it in your code as well as link against it during compilation.

It doesn't matter what you are using, for Qt is a cross platform framework released along with its pretty complete editor, *QtCreator*. It goes without saying that you have to download the library as well as the editor to use them, but I strongly suggest to visit the site (see the link above) for further details and documentation.

Honestly, I don't understand what do you mean by *import Qt in your C++ code*.
How do you *import* the STL in your C++ code? By means of an *include* directive, the same happens for the Qt library. Of course, you have to link against the static or shared libraries once you compile your software and that's all, as with any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Qt is an application development framework. It consists of modular libraries and development tools, including a pretty decent IDE - Qt Creator.

Your Qt installation should not be that big. You are probably installing multiple Qt versions. I haven't used Qt on mac, but on Linux and Windows a single Qt build should not exceed 2.5 GB, the binaries alone are around 2 GB, plus some extra stuff. Add another GB or so if you install the source files as well.

Using Qt is not as simple as "importing into a C++ file" - you need a Qt PRO file, Qt also requires a MOC - metaobject compiler - a phase that generates extra code for you. If you are a beginner you are better off using Qt Creator to create your projects - it will do all the necessary stuff for you. In Creator you can include third party libraries and existing source code. Qt documentation is is fairly good, plus there are plenty of tutorials around the internet as well, so there are plenty of learning resources.